# How to alphabetically order a many-to-many field?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-2.1

I have an object Playlist that is defined in models.py:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    """Allow a user to create a customized list of songs."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='playlists/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=1000)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the model object."""
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    """Returns the url to access a detail record for this song."""
    return reverse('playlist-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

I also have form, AddNewPlaylist that inherits from this model:

```
class AddPlaylistForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ['name', 'image', 'description', 'songs']
```

I would like only the 'songs' object in the form to be ordered alphabetically as it appears in the form - how can I do this?

EDIT: I don't want to change the ordering of the `song` model in the database - only the way that it's ordered in the AddPlayList form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm assuming that in your `models.py`, you have a model named `Song`.  In the `Song` model, I am assuming you have a field `song_name`, or something like it.  In `Song`, add:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('song_name',)
```

This will order all querysets of `Song` objects alphabetically by their name, including the `manytomany` instance of your playlist.

If you want to order specifically the `manytomany` and not all Song querysets, then you should create a `through` model, like this:

```
class PlaylistSong(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('song__song_name',)
```

You can then replace the `songs` field in `Playlist` with:

```
songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, through='PlaylistSong', blank=True)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified:  I don't want to change the way the `Song` model is ordered in the database - only as it is rendered in the form.

Comment: then you should use a through model, and have the `ordering` defined on the through model

Comment: I'm not familiar with through models - can you specify how to do this?  Sorry - very new to this.

Comment: Just updated my answer.  Essentially what you are doing is creating a model that connects the `Playlist` and `Song` models indirectly.  So for each song in a playlist, you have an entry in the `PlaylistSong` table that keeps track of it.  This model is then sorted alphabetically by `song_name`.

Comment: @Leaozinho let me know if it works or if you have a problem still